# SQL Group by on multiple columns

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

My input is:

```
    a b c 
    -------
    A 5 3
    A 4 2
    B 3 1
    B 5 3
```

I would like to get all `a` values having the same values in `b` and `c`, so the output should be as:

```
{A,B} 5 3
```

I am using the `group by`, but I am not achieving my goal.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select b, c, listagg(a, ',') within group (order by a)
from t
group by b, c;
```

Not all databases support `listagg()`, but most have a method for concatenating strings.

In Hive, you would use `collect_list()` or `collect_set()`:

```
select b, c, collect_list(a, ',')
from t
group by b, c;
```

You can convert the array back to a string, but I recommend keeping it as an array.

Comment: I am using HIVE